# DataTables cannot reinitialize or plugin is required

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sorting, datatables

I am having a problem of making my Last Login column to sort by descending 
DataTables automatically sort the data by ascending order of the first column

This is my structure

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url()?>js/dataTables.js"></script>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#example9').dataTable({
        "order": [2,'desc']
});
});
</script>
```

There will be an error saying table_id="#example9" cannot be reinitialize
but the sorting works. When I remove the datatables.js different error appear
datatables plugin is required. How can I solve this ? Advance thank you.

Comment: Can you show the head where you are calling your libraries?

Comment: Are you doing `$('#example9').dataTable(options)` twice?  That's what it sounds like

Comment: @ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ no. the above script is the only script i load for data tables

Comment: But ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ's (wtf?:) analysis is correct - _table_id="#example9" cannot be reinitialized_ clearly indicates that you call `dataTable()` multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

In Datatable, we use aasorting to sort data based on any particular column.
We can use aasorting during initialization of datatable like this

```
$('table').dataTable({
    // display everything
    "aaSorting": [[ 0, "desc" ]] // Sort by first column descending
});
```

Here 0 refers to column number from left. First column is treated as 0 and so on.You can use asc or desc to order your column.

You can read more about such operation [here](http://legacy.datatables.net/ref).

Error `datatable cannot be reinitialize` means you are initialising yout DT multiple times. to check whether your DT is initialised earlier or not

```
if ( ! $.fn.DataTable.isDataTable( '#example' ) ) {
  $('#example').dataTable();
}
```

Read more about this [here](https://datatables.net/reference/api/$.fn.dataTable.isDataTable%28%29).

You can hide all error from screen but they will appear only on console by using

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.sErrMode = 'throw';
```